# example in apple documents for max(by:) operator does not work as described?

Tags: swift, max, documentation, combine

I am new to Combine/now learning the operators,
I followed the example in the apple developer docs but the output was different in playground
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/max(by:)
[image]
//the website shows

```
enum Rank: Int {
    case ace = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king
}

let cards: [Rank] = [.five, .queen, .ace, .eight, .jack]
cancellable = cards.publisher
    .max {
        return  $0.rawValue > $1.rawValue
    }
    .sink { print("\($0)") }

// Prints: "queen"
```

my playground shows:

```
import Combine

enum Rank: Int {
    case ace = 1, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king
}

let cards: [Rank] = [.five, .queen, .ace, .eight, .jack]
cards.publisher
    .max {
        return  $0.rawValue > $1.rawValue
    }
    .sink { print("\($0)") }
//Prints: "ace"
```

I tried to solve the "most common name in an array" problem and it only works when I use "<" not ">" to find the max value/

```
import Combine

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let nameArray: [String] = ["bob", "james", "bob", "james", "lee", "bob", "bob"]

nameArray
    .filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
    .reduce(into: [String: Int]()){ $0[$1] = ($0[$1] ?? 0) + 1 }
    .publisher
    .max {$0.1 < $1.1 }
    .sink{print($0)}
    .store(in: &subscriptions)

//Prints: "(key: "bob", value: 4)"
```

Is it possible the apple document is wrong?
or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you need to use `<` as it says `areInIncreasingOrder` if you need to find the minimum value just use the `min` method instead but the operator still `<`. Btw you can use Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value since Swift 4 `.reduce(into: [:]){ $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }`

Comment: @Leo Dabus so the example in the apple document Is wrong? / thanks for the advise for the default value

Comment: Yes is wrong. If you check the same array method you will see the correct example. You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be right, that this is a bug in the Apple documentation. The note for the argument to `max` says it is:

> **areInIncreasingOrder**
>
> A closure that receives two elements and returns true if they’re in increasing order.

You'll notice that *increasing* order would mean that `$0.rawValue` would be *less* than `$1.rawValue`. The example code uses `>` instead, but still expects `queen` to be printed — this doesn't seem right to me. If I flip around the operator to be `<` instead, it prints `queen` as expected.

I encourage you to file a [Feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) with Apple about this documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried to upvote your answer but i am new and I do not have "15" reputation, I just filed a feedback/

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsAccumulators/operatorsmax.html. Notice the explanation:

> you can supply a function and decide manually *whether the parameters are ordered smaller–larger,* returning a Bool to indicate whether that’s the case.

(My italics.)

But you are saying

```
return  $0.rawValue > $1.rawValue
```

So you are not correctly answering the question whether these are ordered smaller-larger. Instead, say

```
return  $0.rawValue < $1.rawValue
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I read the link you shared/ so the example in apple documents https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/max(by:) might be wrong?